# Access multidimensional associative array using integer index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Assuming I have an associative array which looks like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => array(
            'b' => 'b',
            'c' => 'c',
            'd' => array(
                    'e' =>'e'
            ),
            'f' => 'f',
            'g' => 'g'
    ),
    'h' => 'h',
    'i' => array(
            'j' => 'j',
            'k' => 'k'
    )
);
```

Now I want to access array elements using integer-index:

```
0 will return array of key 'a'  
1 will return array of key 'b'
2 will return array of key 'c'
3 will return array of key 'd'
4 will return array of key 'e'
..
11 will return array of key 'k'
```

I have tried to accomplish this by recursion using the following code:

```
function getElement($arr, $id)
{
    static $counter = 0;

    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        $varNum = count($val);
        $total = $counter + $varNum;
        if($counter == $id){
            return $val;
        }
        elseif($total > $id){
            $counter++;
            $res = getElement($val, $id);
            return $res;
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

However from index 4 the function fails.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive):

```
$list = [];

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($value) use (&$list) {
    $list[] = $value;
});

print_r($list);
```

Will return something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
    [2] => e
    [3] => f
    [4] => g
    [5] => h
    [6] => j
    [7] => k
)
```

---

now to return a full list of keys , you may use the following function:

```
function walk_recursive($arr, &$list = [])
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $ar) {
        if (is_array($ar)) {
            $list[] = $k;
            walk_recursive($ar, $list);
        } else {
            $list[] = $ar;
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
print_r(walk_recursive($arr));
```

this output the following :

```
Array
( 
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
    [7] => h
    [8] => i
    [9] => j
    [10] => k
)
```

live example: https://3v4l.org/Wv0nL

Comment: omg, give me a five minutes, i've wrote this code using my mobile from SO mobile app

Comment: I edited in to use a reference, so it works but not the way OP specified.

Comment: i knew that, i was going to update my answer right now, thank you for that

Comment: @AbraCadaver now i've added new function to get the full list as the OP specified;

Comment: @AbraCadaver the issue with array_walk_recursive that it does not catch the key if it point to another array, i don't know if it's the normal behaviour of array_walk_recusive that it only catch the key => value of the non array elements or not, however thank you for updating my answer;

Comment: I think this will work as OP stated if you change `$list[] = $k;` to `$list[] = $ar;`.  Good one.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thank you for your answer, but it not so efficient. Consider the array as a very large and deeply nested array. I want the values not the keys, which means the new created list can be bloated with all the irrelevant values on the way to the desired position.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$list[] = $ar;` will append the whole nested array into the $list;

Comment: @vintox if you want only the values , you may use the first example using array_walk_recursive, but in your question you specified that you want values as `0 => a, 1 => b ....` , in your array given `a` is a key not a value

Comment: as @AbraCadaver commented, I asked for the array of each key. I used the suggested function with appending the values to the list, however it's very inefficient due to the size of the original array and nesting depth of each inner array element.

Comment: @vintox till now i can't get the point , LOL , as i understood from you that `0 will return array of key 'a' ` that's okey as @AbraCadaver said by returning the array instead of the key, but for this `1 will return array of key 'b'` this should return only b ? right?

Comment: @hassan yes, if the value of the requested key is not an array, it should return the value itself. The array I used is only an example.

Comment: I've updated the answer https://3v4l.org/Wv0nL , it's still following the recursion style, but i don't think that there a way to do without recursion;